# Mapbox GL setData to update layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

In my angular app I am using directions api and trying to add a route path from one direction to another. On the first time when making the ajax request route path is creating properly but from the second time i can not see the route path.

**I am getting this error from second time onwards of the ajax request -  Layer with id "route" already exists on this map**

**Is there any way to update the source and layer in mapbox?**

```
drawRoute() {
const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/${this.startData?.lng},${this.startData?.lat};${this.endData?.lng},${this.endData?.lat}?alternatives=true&geometries=geojson&steps=true&access_token=${environment.mapbox.accessToken}`;

this._http.get(url).subscribe({
    next: (result) => {
        const geojson: any = {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {},
            geometry: {
               type: 'LineString',
               coordinates: result.routes[0]
            }
        };

        if (this.map?.getSource('route')) {
            const source: mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource = this.map?.getSource('route') as 
             mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource;
            source.setData(geojson);
        } else {
            this.map?.addSource('route', {
            type: 'geojson',
                data: {
                    type: 'Feature',
                    properties: {},
                    geometry: {
                       type: 'LineString',
                       coordinates: result.routes[0].geometry.coordinates
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        this.map?.addLayer({
            id: 'route',
            type: 'line',
            source: 'route',
            layout: {
                'line-join': 'round',
                'line-cap': 'round'
            },
            paint: {
              'line-color': '#1F5ED8',
              'line-width': 2
            }
        });
    },
    error: (err) => {} 
})
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think that the `setData()` method that is available for GeoJSON sources in Mapbox GL JS is what you are looking for. The method allows you to update the underlying source data and triggers a map re-render. The data-driven styling should then kick in and style your updates layers as desired.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/sources/#geojsonsource#setdata

Here is a pseudo-code example

```js
map.getSource("source-id").setData(updatedGeoJSONData);
```

Hope this helps! I have been writing a series of guides for Mapbox that you might be interested in too. Here are some links:

- [The Mapbox Developer's Handbook](https://gumroad.com/l/mapbox-handbook)
- [A Complete Guide to Sources and Layers in React and Mapbox GL JS](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/a-complete-guide-to-sources-and-layers-in-react-and-mapbox-gl-js)

Comment: this definitely worked for me! thanks.